# window.open is not working with Java Script and IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I have an issue to use `window.open` with internet explorer

My java script is as below

```
var data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(excelFile);
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;filename=test;' + data);
```

It is meant to download an Excel made by JQUERY /JS and it is functional in all other browsers.
Could you help to make it work with IE or any other alternate of `window.open`?

Comment: wich version of IE? Not related to apps for office (office.js)?

Comment: Hello,Its is IE11